# We don't need a [vps]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

Found this <s>interesting</s> uninteresting tag: [vps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vps). As its wiki and excerpt suggests, it refers to Virtual Private Server.

Certainly Stack Overflow isn't about server setup or maintenance, and look at [its questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vps), pick a few at random, and **this tag adds no value**. To elaborate:

- In most cases where the OP is on a VPS, [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) should suffice, possibly with other tags describing server environment (OS / distro [debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debian) or software versions [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8)),

  Or worse, it's not really about [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) so such tags should be dropped altogether
- In case it's really *about* [vps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vps), it should be off-topic ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66940864))
- Or if it's about VPS and on-topic? **I don't think so**

I believe either of these actions should be taken:

- Synonymize [vps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vps) into [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server)
- Rewrite [vps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vps) to `/dev/null`

Comment: Is _server_ itself an appropriate tag? I don't see its value.

Comment: Perhaps *"Make [vps] virtually private"*? Or *"Demote [vps] to [serve as private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_(rank))"*?

Answer (score 24):

I'm not sure synonimizing VPS to server will solve anything.

Both are littered with trash, and VPS questions are about networking and virtual machines in part too, so we could argue virtual-machine is a better target.

A quick look at the VPS tag shows a bunch of off-topic issues regarding configuring a server, a bunch of off-topic questions regarding network administration on VPSes (which is a distinct class since a VPS often has a shared network adapter which can lead to configuration issues, retagging these to server would be a bad move if they were on-topic), a bunch of general Linux questions which are also off topic, and nearly zero on-topic questions that should be answered here but would do better with the server tag.

I think we should either go for a full burnination or leave it be. Redirecting questions about VPSes to server will probably only lead to more trash on server, and not really solve anything. If we want to make it clear that questions about VPSes are off-topic, there shouldn't be a synonym.

Removing bad tags by synonymizing them to slightly less bad tags is not something that solves anything, in my opinion. A VPS is distinct from any server in the broad sense, so if they both were on topic having distinct tags makes sense. If we want it gone because it's off topic, adding a synonym is not the way to go.

The only real argument I can think of to go for a synonym is that the burnination process is slow and requires a lot of effort, but that's because the community decided it should.

Comment: I am aware of a couple of questions where [tag:vps] was exceedingly relevant to the question though. One case in particular, the VPS had oversubscribed the disk. Give the fact it was on a VPS and the problem description I was able to confidently answer the problem was in the VPS not in the code.

Comment: @Joshua: But did it need a [vps] *tag* for you to get that info about the setup in the question?  Sounds like the kind of detail about system environment that all questions should include when it applies, but we don't want all questions about some problem happening on an ubuntu system to be tagged [ubuntu].